# html/php content not rendering on view source until page refresh

Tags: php, html, wordpress, refresh, view-source

I'm integrating an iframe with dynamic php content in its src on a checkout congratulations page. When the process is complete the iframe with code shows in Firebug, but not on view source in the browser. If I refresh the page the content shows in the browser view source. This, is what I believe, is causing the integration to fail because the iframe is not being picked up by the online service we are using.

Its a Wordpress so the final page calls `get_header();` then html/php then `get_footer();`. Everything in between the header and footer does not show on the view source until I refresh the page, very odd. I tried googling but I found nothing and I'm not sure what even may cause it or where to begin.
Any experience with this?

Edit.
below is the code, everything inside of and including `section1` div does not show in view source.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>


<div class="section1">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">

        <iframe here>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Edit:
I still don't know why, but it had to do with destroying all PHP session and browser cookies. Time to mark this one closed. If I ever figure out why,
I'll edit this question.

Comment: hard to solve this without details...your html above is not the cause.